# PHP Fatal Error: Out of Memory when creating an image

Tags: php, gd

I have a simple PHP script that takes an image that's been uploaded and processes it with `imagecreatefromjpeg`. It works great on small images, but not on larger ones. With an image of say, 5,799,936 bytes, I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 56623104) (tried to allocate 3072 bytes)`

If the image is less than 1MB, I get no such error.

I've ensured that I always use `imagedestroy` whenever an image has been successfully processed, and I've used `memory_get_usage()` to see what's currently in use (186260).

Is there anyway to get to the bottom of this error and change the outcome -- or do I need to put a check in place for the size of the image, as the server will never be able to process anything of that size. (If so, how can I tell what size is OK for the server?)

Comment: Increasing `allowed_memory` in php.ini is not an option?

Comment: This has plenty of duplicates on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TobiasKun No. It's shared hosting unfortunately.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I couldn't find one that gave an answer to the questions I'm asking.

Answer (score 3):

It is not *file* size but *image* size require certain amount of memory. And you can get required dimensions from familiar `getimagesize()` function.

To calculate the dimensions limits just get the resizable file, get it's dimensions, measure consumed memory with `memory_get_peak_usage()` and divide it by the number ofpixels in the image. Yu will get the rough coefficient which will tell you dimensions which you allowed to

Comment: Your answer isn't easy to follow, but I think I get what you're saying: It's the *dimensions* of the image that are causing the problem, and I can figure out what the maximum allowable dimensions are using `memory_get_peak_usage()` (I get 197564 returned -- not sure I can get the peak usage during the processing, though). The image dimensions are: 3072x4096. Pretty huge.

Comment: @Django for every pixel, you will need four bytes - Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha. When resizing is in play, the need will be a multiple of that because the original image will likely have to reside in memory during the process.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for your help. That means the image will require 50,331,648 bytes. If I resize the image 75% in Photoshop, it then requires 28,311,552 bytes -- which works fine. I just can't see the correlation between `memory_get_peak_usage()` (197564 bytes) though?

Comment: @Django maybe `memory_get_peak_usage()` needs the 1st parameter set to `true`? Not sure, I have little experience with it

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, the documentation on PHP.net is lacking. With the parameter set to TRUE I get 262144.

Comment: Ok, I just tried a bunch of files of different sizes. Basically it should be less than 10,200,000 pixels. If it's over that, I throw an exception. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For true-color image, GD allocates five bytes per pixel: red, green, blue, alpha, and one byte for anti-aliasing operations. That's in addition to the four/eight bytes per scanline for pointers and bytes lost to memory alignment.

Answer (score 2):

The way  @Common Sense outlines is the only way to *try* and predict how much memory a resize process is going to consume. It's never going to be 100% accurate but with the right safety margins, it'll likely be adequate.

Another option that comes to mind is to trigger a separate PHP process that attempts the resize operation (through `file_get_contents` or `exec()`). If that operation fails with a fatal error, you can catch it and show a friendly message to the user that their image is too large.

If you can get binaries installed on your server, you could also consider relying on an external tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to do the resizing. A command-line tool's memory usage does not count towards your PHP memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) and [Pekka웃](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) I tried various pixel dimensions until I got a rough idea of the number that could be handled by the server. For me it was around 10,200,000 pixels in a single image.

I then used `getimagesize()` to get the height and width of any uploaded image, and checked to see the total number of pixels. If it was more than 10,200,000, I throw an exception before I get to `imagecreatefromjpeg`, letting the user know to resize and image.